# Typescript: export interface with different name

Tags: typescript

I need to import interface, add property to id and export the new interface with the same name as original one. Then in all places where this interface is used I can only change import location.

```
import { Routes, Route } from '@angular/router';
interface Route2 extends Route {
    description: string;
}

export declare type Routes = Route2[];
```

And then I'd like to (although it is not possible)

```
export Route2 as Route;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the original `Route` under a different name and export the new one as `Route`

```
import { Route as OriginalRoute } from '@angular/router';
export interface Route extends OriginalRoute {
    description: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with ***export type*** which allows you to provide an alias for the interface.

General example (Alias being the new name and SomeInterface the original):

```
export type Alias = SomeInterface;
```

Your specific scenario:

```
import { Routes, Route } from '@angular/router';
    interface Route2 extends Route {
        description: string;
    }

export type Route = Route2;
```